# How do I delete a phone number from Facebook?

Tags: facebook, facebook-profile

On my Facebook profile, I accidentally put my mobile number in the section for my home number.

[image: mobile number in the section for my home number]

When I try to move it to the mobile section I get an error: "This phone number already exists in your account."

How can I delete the home number, or move it to the mobile section?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do it in two steps:

- Step one: delete it from the *Other Phones* section and click *Save*.
- Step two: add it to the *Mobile Phones* section and click *Save*.

The thing is to save the edit between deleting it from one section and adding it to another one.

(I just tested it and it works.)